Proposition 12 Corollary 1, Section 5.6 of Hungerford’s Algebra
Lemma 6.11. Let $F$ be an extension field of $E$, $E$ an extenion field of $K$ and $N$ a normal extension field of $K$ containing $F$. If $r$ is the cardinal number of distinct $E$-monomorphisms $F\to N$ and $t$ is the cardinal number of distinct $K$-monomorphisms $E\to N$, then $rt$ is the cardinal number of distinct $K$-monomorphisms $F\to N$.
Proposition 6.12. Let $F$ be a finite dimensional extension field of $K$ and $N$ a normal extension field of $K$ containing $F$. The number of distinct $K$-monomorphisms $F\to N$ is precisely $[F : K]_s$, the separable degree of $F$ over $K$.


If $F$ is an extension field of $E$ and $E$ is an extension field of $K$, then $[F:E]_s[E:K]_s=[F:K]_s$ and $[F:E]_i[E:K]_i=[F:K]_i$.
Proof: Exercise; use Lemma 6.11 and Proposition 6.12.

Did the author forget to mention $F$ is finite dimensional extension of $K$ or this result holds for infinite dimensional extension? If $F$ is arbitrary extension of $K$, then we might not even have $N$ normal extension of $K$ containing $F$. Am I right?

Separable degree $[F:K]_s$ is equal to the number of morphisms that denoted by $\sigma$: $F$ $\to$ $K$ª that fixes $K$.
And, $[F:K]_i$ is equal to $[F:K]/[F:K]_s$.
Let $\sigma$: $k→L$ be an embedding of $k$ in an algebraically closed field $L$. Let {$\sigma_i$} be the family of distinct extensions of $σ$ to $F$, and for each $i$, and, let {$\tau_{ij}$} be the family of distinct extensions of $σ$; to $E$. By what we saw before, each $σ$; has precisely $[E: F]_s$ extensions to embeddings of $E$ in $L$. The set of embeddings ${ij}$ contains precisely
$[E:F]_s[F:k]_s$
elements. Any embedding of $E$ into $L$ over σ must be one of the $\tau_{ij}$.
And, $[E:F]_i[F:K]_i$ = $[E:F][F:K]$ ÷ $[E:F]_s[F:K]_s$, then it is immediate by multiplication rule of separable degree.
